# How to Configure Sync Center / Offline Files within a IIS Shared Configuration Environment to sync when user is logged off?

Tags: windows-server-2016, mappeddrive, iis-10, offline-files

We've been scratching our heads at this and we are not sure if this is a design limitation of sync center or are missing something on our server.

Our environment consists of a cluster of WS2016 boxes and we have enabled offline files on each server to store a local copy of the shared configuration from the specified share path, have configured the cache to read only and configured a schedule to sync every minute.

While the user is logged in the schedule works fine - so as our next step we updated the sync center hidden task schedule to have it run whether the user is logged in or not within Task Scheduler -> microsoft -> windows -> sync center -> {userguid} -> {syncguid}

The result is that if the user is logged off it does not run and if others users (view) this task that log into this server it reports either (access denied) or an (identity issue).

Our configuration changes periodically and we want to make sure the cache is always up to date in case our remote share goes done is there a way to get this running while the user is logged off?

Also as a side question is it possible to enable all users to see the configured partnership within sync center as it's invisible to other users?

Best regards and thank you for you efforts.

Comment: No offense, but this sounds like a horrible solution. Why don't you just back up the shared configuration using standard backup methodologies?

Comment: Non taken I'm open to solutions but, our shared configuration is hosted on a share that is highly available and there is no (backup) concerns. The issue is if maintenance occurs on this remote centralized storage and it goes down momentarily the IIS app pools will crash since it cannot find the IIS Shared Config, the recommendation is to use offline files to temporarily fill in that gap but, that depends on when the last sync ocurred else you would end up switching to an older iis shared config setup...

Comment: Understood. I've never heard of using Offline Files in this scenario and it sounds like its more trouble than it's worth and may not be do-able. Have you considered using a highly available share to host the shared configuration?

Comment: Appreciate your insight joeqwerty it likely is more trouble than it's worth and after doing some more research it looks like configuring DFS Replication across the web farm or even a setting up a task scheduled robocopy script to sync shared config content locally on each server might be the better approach instead of offline sync.